# Offsetting two geom_points of the same category

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot this data:

```
data(comp)

Habitat Used Available  SDU  SDA
1    Forest 63.2      85.1 32.0 12.8
2      Open 18.9       3.3 24.8  1.4
3      Edge 15.4       7.8 10.0  4.6
4   Wetland  2.5       1.2  6.1  3.5
5 Developed  0.0       3.5  0.0  6.7
```

using this code:

```
ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=comp,size=3,fill="white",shape=21,aes(x=Habitat,y=Available))+
  geom_errorbar(data=comp,aes(x=Habitat,ymin=Available-SDA,ymax=Available+SDA,width=.1))+

  geom_point(data=comp,size=3,fill="black",shape=21,aes(x=Habitat,y=Used))+
  geom_errorbar(data=comp,aes(x=Habitat,ymin=Used-SDU,ymax=Used+SDU,width=.1))+

  theme_classic()
```

which gives me this
[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaODc.png):

Excellent!

However, those error bars cannot be read, as they are overlapping! How can I offset the two points (perhaps used to the "left", and "available" to the right) so that I can see each errorbar properly?

I have tried position_dodge, and geom_jitter instead of geom_point, but I cannot get those to work. I have tried searching, but I haven't had much success.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your data to "long" format and you can then map Used and Available to a color aesthetic. This makes it easier to distinguish them, reduces the amount of code needed, and makes it easy to dodge them (using `position_dodge()`) so they don't overlap:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

comp.m = melt(comp, id.var="Habitat")
comp.m = data.frame(comp.m[1:10,], err=comp.m[11:20,3])

pd = position_dodge(0.5)

ggplot(comp.m) +
  geom_point(aes(Habitat, value, color=variable), position=pd) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(Habitat, ymin=value - err, ymax=value + err,
                    color=variable), width=0.3, position=pd) +
  theme_classic() +
  labs(color="")
```

[image]